# Tab inline content inside Colorbox , tabs wont work

Tags: jquery, tabs, colorbox

I am trying to display tabbed content inside a colorbox modal window. But the tabbed navigation wont work at all...

I think that problem is the **rel** thing but i am novice in jquery

Here is the Working Link for the actual page [SignUp modal widnow problem](http://www.coffeedesign.net/qme/mainpage.html)

A screenshot is here
[colorbox modal window with tabs screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/0kPnpIZB7)

[Pastebin code link](http://pastebin.com/N8FqQ77U)

Can you guide me what changes i need to make to my jquery script to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".tab_content_form").hide();
        $(".tab_content_form:first").show();

        $("ul.tabs_form li").click(function() {
                console.log('clicked !');
                $("ul.tabs_form li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).addClass("active");
                $(".tab_content_form").hide();
                var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
                $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();
        });
});
```

Comment: you are using the `.click()` method, which is only applied to elements that exists when it is invoked. If your elements are retrieved via AJAX ( you mentioned a colorbox ), you should be using [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: No i am not calling anything with ajax, i want the tabs to work inside an inline colorbox   $(".inline1").colorbox({inline:true, width:"786px" ,height:"409px"});